# HTML left arrow ("<") not working when creating PDF file

Tags: php, html, pdf, fpdf

I have a problem with the FPDF class (very useful imho) which I'm using in my web page. I have a HTML table with some values, also with the "arrows" chars which in fact are causing the problem, but,  especially with the left one ("<"). When I try to create my PDF file it works until it finds that character, and it shows nothing after that point.
All i've tried until now is this:

```
str_replace("<","&#60;");
```

or

```
str_replace("<","&lt;");
```

but nothing is working so far. Does anyone know how to make this working? Seems like the PDF recognize it as an opening HTML tag and I don't know how to show that char

Comment: double-encoding, perhaps? `&amp;lt;`?

Comment: not working, it shows "&lt". I think the problem is that FPDF is interpreting the arrow char as an initial HTML tag

Comment: Reading `fdpf17/fpdfp.php`, I find no evidence this module is supposed to support HTML out of the box. In particular, it doesn't seem to parse *anything* related to HTML. The function `_escape` only escapes `(`, `)`, ``\`` and `\r`. Can you add some more of the relevant code?